# Unable to open admin panel after successful installation of magento on localhost in ubuntu 14.04.

Tags: magento, ubuntu

I am trying to setup magento on my localhost. I followed all the instructions from here: http://www.unixmen.com/install-magento-ubuntu-15-04/ and successfully installed magento. 
[image]

But i am unable to open admin panel and getting following error:

The requested URL /admin_eoyh6q/ was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80

I am able to open store home page but seems like some css is missing and none of the links present on this page are working and giving same error as admin panel.

I am using Magento 2 and have unzipped my Magento-CE-2.0.2+sample_data-2016-01-28-02-46-48.tar.gz in /var/www/html.

I am using Magento for the first time so i might be missing some simple steps, kindly guide me on this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @Enigmativity Thanks for the suggestion, i will post it on magento.stackexchange.com, but i wish to ask that does SO cover questions related to setup/installation of any type of technology(framework/cms/library) or it covers only coding part?

Comment: Have a read of what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: @Enigmativity it mentions- software tools commonly used by programmers, i thought frameworks and cms are considered in software tools.

Comment: Frameworks count if the purpose of the framework is for you to do coding, but not for configuration of software that happens to use a framework. I can't think of when a CMS counts, unless it has a direct link to programming. What's on-topic is pretty narrow.

Comment: @Enigmativity Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You may delete or rename your `.htaccess` file and see if you able to open admin panel.

Comment: @waqt.ga can you please guide me where to find this .htaccess file. Is this file hidden? I am able to find one htaccessfile in zf directory of zend framework but i don't think you meant this file. Kindly provide directory structure of location of this file.

Comment: open your directory through ftp and look in your admin directory, and if it do not work delete also htaccess in your root dir